# Rendering problem on a procedural cloud

Tags: rendering, volumetrics, procedural, compositing-nodes

I created a procedural cloud with this tutorial : https://youtu.be/lCvP917Z8uc, but when I duplicate it to create a "Clouds carpet" the invisible cube from which I created my cloud causes my rendering to bug.
I render with cycles.
[image]

[image]

[image]

The rendering from the camera gives that.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked out the video, and I recommend moving one of the cubes a tiny bit so that faces are not directly overlapping. That has caused this kind of thing before.

Comment: My problem is that if the faces do not overlap my two clouds are separated and cannot give a "clouds carpet" effect.

Comment: Not overlapping cubes, overlapping faces. Just move one cube by 0.01 m in the x and z directions.

Comment: Alt: For a carpet, you might be better off with one large cloud. Does it need to be small puffs of cloud?